# "Key to" vs. "key for"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, to-for

> Key to exercises.

Today I saw the quoted sentence when looking at the keys *to* exercises, and afterwards that sentence got me thinking why the preposition *to* is used here 
instead of *for*.

The way I see it is that the key purpose is to match our answer with the correct one; hence, *for* would fit here nicely.  Am I right?

Comment: Because keys in the standard sense go to locks.

Comment: I've heard them used interchangeably, so the answer might well be subtle or paved over by misuse.

Comment: If I'm understanding this question correctly, I would simply use the term "[Answer Key](http://www.iseek.org/iseek/static/AnswerKeys_10.pdf)" and avoid the preposition altogether.

Comment: I suspect there is a similar principle in effect when stating "the answer *to* your question is" versus "the answer *for* your question is", but I don't know if this is indicative of some English rule or just a "fact" of general usage. It reminds me of the difference between *por* and *para* in Spanish, though.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I never heard or read "key of something", and I consume quite a lot of english content

Comment: @Alex “key of the door”, “keys of the castle”, “key of the safe” … a common usage.

Comment: "Key to" if [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=key+to%2Ckey+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&case_insensitive=true), despite "key of" being used for music (e.g., "in the key of C").

Comment: There is no quoted sentence here.  The quotation is a noun phrase.  It lacks a verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in comment, *keys* in the standard sense pair with *locks*.  Copies can be made, but in theory, each lock has only one key that unlocks it.  See also:

- [keys to the kingdom](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keys_to_the_kingdom)
- key to my heart
- [under lock and key](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/under+lock+and+key)

Comment: I'd go for the same expression you indicate, that is *"key to"*; however, the OP indicated *"for"* as the preposition of his choice, so your last sentence is not entirely suitable.

Comment: "Do you have the key for the back door?": Perfectly normal idiomatic English.

Answer (score -4):

I can see using “key to” when the “to” is part of a verb phrase.  “The key to unlock the door is under the mat.”  “The key to understanding the problem was remembering PEMDAS.”

If a preposition and a linking verb are used, perhaps “for” is a better choice. "To stay healthy, the key for me is watching my weight."

Comment: In "the key to understanding the problem", the part after *to* is a noun phrase, not a verb phrase. *To* is a preposition there. In "the key to unlock the door", *to* is part of the *infinitive*; of course you can call it a verb phrase if you must, but that's unnecessarily misleading. It looks like you opted for the term only to have a convenient (but wrong) hypernym.

Comment: @RegDwigнt is it really part of the infinitive or is it a preposition expressing the purpose of the key or the instrumental relationship between the key and the door?  Or is that function of the preposition the thing that led to our considering "to" as part of the infinitive, unlike more inflected languages ?